# Blazor Server-Side .Net 8 Not Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor-server-side, .net-8.0

I've being facing a problem with redirection. I will explaining my problem into 2 cases

**Case 1**:

Redirection to `<NotFound>` page never succeed. What am I missing here?

**Case 2**:

Redirection to `Login` page succeed at local development but not when I deployed to IIS. Everything work like it should at local but when at server I'm facing error `HTTP ERROR 500`. Below are the lines I've been tried so far.

I'm using a controller for authentication process, the redirection I've made at controller seems ok it redirect me to `/home` after successful login also the logout process seems ok.

P/S: I created the `BlankLayout.razor` in the folder `Layout`

`Routes.razor`

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="typeof(Program).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="routeData" DefaultLayout="typeof(Layout.MainLayout)" >
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <RedirectToLogin />
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="typeof(Layout.BlankLayout)">
                <p>There is nothing over here</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

`RedirectToLogin`

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(NavigationManager.Uri)}", forceLoad: true);
    }
}
```

`Program.cs`

```
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
builder.Services.AddCascadingAuthenticationState();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(x =>
    {
        x.LoginPath = "/login";
        x.LogoutPath = "/auth/logout";
    });

builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddScoped<CookieEvent>();
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(x =>
{
    x.EventsType = typeof(CookieEvent);
});
```

Comment: Hello Jack, could you kindly check the url rewrite module has been installed in your IIS server or not? And we may also could enable failed request tracing rules to find more details.

Comment: Hi Jason, I don't think I've download the url rewrite module yet at my IIS. Does it required in order to host a blazor web app? Sorry, I'm very new to this framework

Comment: Hi Jack， I am not sure, I just compare what the difference between your server and mine. If the issue is easy to reproduce, do you mind create a brand new project without any sensitive information for me, I am willing to investigate it.

Comment: Can you share your `App.razor` file?

Comment: Hi all, thank you for the reply. Please take a look [Link](https://github.com/hafiziezakaria/TestCase_NotRedirect)

Comment: I have deployed it in my server, it works fine. Not facing the redirect issue. I have installed the url rewrite module.

Comment: I remembered that the [URLRewrite Module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) is necessary. The official documentation does not explain it, but it can run normally after installation.

Comment: And for NotFound issue, it's a known issue in .net8 template, and [here is the workaround  for you](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52660#issuecomment-1855740591). Please let me know if it works for you, if it works, please allow me summarize it as answer, thanks~

Comment: Hi Jason, I think maybe I missed the url rewrite part. Please share your step at the answer section so that I have a better understanding. And for the `<NotFound>` I'll try to look at the link given. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Jack, I have post my answer, you can check it. Have a nice day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps to reproduce the issue.

**Step 1** Create a brand new server and install IIS and asp.net core Hosting Bundle.

[image]

[image]

**Step 2** Reproduce the issue.

[image]

**Step 3** Download url rewrite here.( https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and install it.

[image]

**Step 4** Close the IIS Manager.

[image]

**Step 5** Refresh the tab page in browser. The tab1 for comparing.

[image]

#### After testing, the url rewrite is needed.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for the step. After following your guide, unfortunately I still got the `ERROR 500` when tried to trigger the `<RedirectToLogin /> component. It does not redirect me to the login page.

Comment: Hi Jack, share me the detailed error message, many thanks

Comment: Hi Jason, the [photo](https://i.imgur.com/2DMa6Jv.png) is snapped after I published to IIS. I tried to test the `<RedirectToLogin>` but I'm keep getting this error.

Comment: Hello @JackJack, could you kindly share the repo(if it don't have sensitve/business  informations) or create a brand new project for me, I am willing to help you check the issue.

Comment: @JackJack Usually the 500 means IIS server or the web application has some issues, we may find the error details in EventViewer. If we have the repo for testing, we can fix the issue asap.

Comment: Hi Jason, please have a look [Link](https://github.com/hafiziezakaria/TestCase_NotRedirect)

Comment: Hello @JackJack, my mistake, I have already check your repo before, could you reply me(@ my nickname) actively, then we can chat each other, many thanks

Comment: Hi @Jason Pan sure looking forward to have a chat with you!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257201/discussion-between-jason-pan-and-jackjack).